# Spring Data Elastic Search: remove low disk watermark warning

Tags: java, elasticsearch, spring-data, spring-data-elasticsearch

I'm getting constant warnings `low disk watermark exceeded` while running Spring Data embedded Elastic Search.

Normally when running a separate ES server I would get rid of these types of warnings by configuring Elastic Search configuration file.

Is there a way to specify some config parameter in .properties file or in a `@Configuration` Java class to turn this warning off in the embedded Spring Data ES version?

Thanks!

EDIT:

**ElasticSearchConfiguration.class**

```
@Configuration
@EnableElasticsearchRepositories(basePackages = "eu.step.search")
public class ElasticSearchConfiguration {
    @Bean
    public ElasticsearchTemplate elasticsearchTemplate (Client client, Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder) {
        return new ElasticsearchTemplate(client, new CustomEntityMapper(jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder.createXmlMapper(false).build()));
    }

    public class CustomEntityMapper implements EntityMapper {

        private ObjectMapper objectMapper;

        public CustomEntityMapper (ObjectMapper objectMapper) {
            this.objectMapper = objectMapper;
            objectMapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);
            objectMapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.ACCEPT_SINGLE_VALUE_AS_ARRAY, true);
        }

        @Override
        public String mapToString (Object object) throws IOException {
            return objectMapper.writeValueAsString(object);
        }

        @Override
        public <T> T mapToObject (String source, Class <T> clazz) throws IOException {
            return objectMapper.readValue(source, clazz);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out you can do it by specifying the following parameter in **application.properties**:

```
spring.data.elasticsearch.properties.cluster.routing.allocation.disk.threshold_enabled=false
```

Answer (score 1):

When building your node you can specify the adequate configuration settings:

```
    ImmutableSettings.Builder settingsBuilder = ImmutableSettings.settingsBuilder();

    settingsBuilder.put("node.name", "MyNode");
    settingsBuilder.put("cluster.routing.allocation.disk.threshold_enabled", "false");
    Settings settings = settingsBuilder.build();

    node = NodeBuilder.nodeBuilder()
                      .settings(settings)
                      .clusterName("MyCluster")
                      .local(true).node();
```